# How to slice a slice for eliminating matching values from identical slice

Tags: go

I'm looking for an easy way to iterate through a slice and on every value that's present in the current slice, remove the element from another slice.

I have a struct:

```
    a := enter{
        uid: 1234,
        status: []StatusEntry{
            {
                rank:    1,
                iterate: ierationState_Ongoing,
            },
            {
                rank:    2,
                iterate: ierationState_Completed,
            },

        },
    }
```

In my .go file, I have a constant

```
Steps = [5]int64{0,1,2,3,4}
```

According to my requirement I want to copy the Steps in another variable and perform remove operation :

```
Steps2 := Steps   // Make a copy of Steps

for _, element := enter.status {
     // Remove that element from Steps

}
```

But I find it difficult to do so since Golang doesn't give me direct method to iterate and remove every element from enter.status from Steps.

I tried multiple things like creating a removeIndex function as posted on various stackoverflow answers like this:

```
for i, element := enter.status {
        Steps2 = removeIndex(enter.status, i)
}
```

```
func removeIndex(s []int, index int) []int {
    ret := make([]int, 0)
    ret = append(ret, s[:index]...)
    return append(ret, s[index+1:]...)
}
```

But it doesn't make sense to use this because I'm trying to remove a matching value (element) and not a specific index (for eg index 5) from Steps2.

Basically, for every element that's in slice `enter.status`, I want to remove that element/value from slice `Steps2`

Answer (score 0):

Careful:

> ```
> [5]int64{0,1,2,3,4}
> ```

This is an *array* (of 5 `int`s), not a slice.  And:

> ```
> Steps2 := Steps
> ```

If `Steps` were a slice, this would copy the *slice header* without copying the underlying array.

In any case, given some slice `s` of type `T` and length `len(s)`, if you are allowed to modify `s` in place and order is relevant, you generally want to use this algorithm:

```
func trim(s []T) []T {
    out := 0
    for i := range s {
        if keep(s[i]) {
            s[out] = s[i]
            out++
        }
    }
    return s[:out]
}
```

where `keep` is your boolean function to decide whether to keep an element.  To make this produce a *new* slice, allocate an output slice of the appropriate length (`len(s)`) at the start and optionally shrink it later, or, if you expect to throw out most elements, make it empty at the start and use `append`.

When the `keep` function is "the value of some field in the output slice does not match the value of any earlier kept field" *and* the type of that field is usable as a key type, you can use a simple `map[T2]struct{}` to determine whether the value has occurred yet:

```
    seen := make(map[T2]struct{}, len(s))
```

and then the `keep` test and copy sequence becomes:

```
    _, ok := seen[s[i].field]
    if !ok {
        seen[s[i].field] = struct{}{}
        s[out] = s[i]
        out++
    }
```

The initial size of `seen` here is optimized on the theory that most values will be kept; if most values will be discarded, make the map initially empty, or small.